# SQL: How can I select top 1 row, based on different criteria on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have a table which has a column named `ItemCode`, it has fixed format xxx-xxxx where x is [0-9], for example a possible value of `ItemCode` is 097-1234

Now I would like to select the largest `ItemCode` which starts with `987` AND the last `ItemCode` starts with `123`, so I am trying to do something like (This is wrong)

```
SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode From Table 
WHERE ItemCode like '987%' OR ItemCode like '123%'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

So how can I write a SQL which can select the last `ItemCode` of each criteria? Is there any general method which can extend to select top `N` rows on `M` such criterias?

(assuming there exists data fulfills the criteria, here 2 rows should be returned: largest `ItemCode` starts with `987` and largest `ItemCode` starts with `123`)

Comment: Do a UNION ALL.

Comment: Will all of your criteria always be based on the 3 character element that starts `ItemCode`? (P.S. if the elements before/after the dash are meaningful in and of themselves, you may want to consider splitting them into separate columns and only combining them with a dash for *presentation* in a computed column - thus avoiding the need to use string manipulation to re-extract the elements)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the tips, I am trying to use UNION / UNION ALL to see if I can solve the problem

Damien_The_Unbeliever, Understood and thanks very much. They are meaningful in some sense but is not related to the task I am trying to achieve. So yes all of the criteria will always be based on the 3 characters prefix

Comment: @jarlh  Thanks, I have achieved what I need.

Comment: What is "the largest item"? How could I get it?

Comment: @TriV lexicographically largest, which can simply get by adding `ORDER BY DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE for a more generalised form:

```
;With Ordered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ItemCode,1,3)
            ORDER BY ItemCode desc) as rn
    from
        Table
    where
        ItemCode like '987%' or
        ItemCode like '123%'
)
select *
from Ordered
where rn = 1
```

As I alluded to in the comments, if possible I'd change the structure so that the `ItemCode` elements are separately stored, which would make for a simpler internal query form that could also more easily benefit from indexes. E.g. something like:

```
;With Ordered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ItemCode_Prefix
            ORDER BY ItemCode_Suffix desc) as rn
    from
        Table
    where
        ItemCode_Prefix in (987,123)
)
select *
from Ordered
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! I am not familiar with CTE, is it by any means a better approach than @Triv's solution which looks similar but cleaner and shorter?

Comment: @shole - they probably produce identical execution plans, once the ordering is fixed. In general, I tend to favour CTEs as a more general mechanism - TriVs answer relies upon being able to create a single expression that is acceptable in an `ORDER BY` clause, whereas mine defines the row numbers separately and could then apply arbitrary additional transformations. At the end of the day, pick whatever *reads best* to you and that has *acceptable* performance. If you want to choose between alternatives, always compare plans to see if they're in any way actually different.

Answer (score 2):

Another option without `UNION`, you could use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
From YourTable 
WHERE ItemCode like '987%' OR ItemCode like '123%'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(ItemCode,3) ORDER BY Itemcode DESC)
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` is still applying an *arbitrary* ordering with no guarantee that the "highest" will be assigned row number 1.

Comment: The OP commented above and only wants "lexicographically largest, which can simply get by adding ORDER BY 1 DESC". I think the OP doesn't want to order by itemCode.

Comment: But `ORDER BY 1 DESC`, when it's the `ORDER BY` clause is using `1` to indicate the first column in the `SELECT` clause. I.e. their query is actually sorting on the `ItemCode` column. *Your* query is giving every row the same constant value to sort on and so is *arbitrary*. The system tries to help *protect* you with an error by not allowing `ORDER BY 1 DESC` in the window clause. The use of `(SELECT 1)` instead of `1` is just tricking the optimizer into not raising the error but *the logical error remains*.

Comment: Ok. I think it's not clear how to get the largest Itemcode. ItemCode is varchar and the OP should make it more clearly.

Comment: @TriV Thanks, I have tried your code, but as Damien said, it return two rows, which is giving me ascending order results. However if I change `SELECT 1` to `ItemCode`, it returns correct result. That gives you an upvote, but I am still thinking is this short, clean solution better than Damien's CTE solution (I am not familiar with CTE...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jarlh, I used `UNION` to achieve what I need.

If anyone has a more general method which may easier to be extended to more criteria, please post an answer and I will accept it. Cheers.

```sql
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode FROM Table
    WHERE ItemCode LIKE '987%'
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
) AS A
UNION
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode FROM Table
    WHERE ItemCode LIKE '123%'
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
) AS B
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution based on ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
use tempdb;
go

-- Test data
create table #test_data
(ItemCode char(8) not null);

insert into #test_data
values 
  ('097-1234'),
  ('097-1243'),
  ('097-7890'),
  ('012-1234'),
  ('912-1234'),
  ('123-1234'),  -- second max for '987,123'
  ('123-1234'),
  ('123-0001'),
  ('123-0932'),
  ('987-1234'),
  ('987-5643'),
  ('987-7890'),  -- first max for '987,123'
  ('000-7890');
go
-- Test data

-- Code
create proc dbo.top_n_from_m
  @criterias varchar(max)
as
  set nocount on;

  declare @crs table 
    (id int not null identity (1, 1) primary key,
     string char(3) not null);

  insert into @crs (string)
  select value
  from string_split(@criterias, ',')

  select t.ItemCode
  from 
    (select t.ItemCode,
            c.id, 
            row_id = row_number() over (partition by c.id order by t.ItemCode desc)
    from #test_data as t
      join @crs as c on t.ItemCode like c.string + '-%') as t
  where t.row_id = 1
  order by t.id
go
-- Code

-- Test
execute dbo.top_n_from_m @criterias = '987,123'

select ItemCode
from #test_data
order by ItemCode
-- Test

-- Clear
drop table #test_data;
drop proc dbo.top_n_from_m;
-- Clear
```